# Статичные переменные c# применяемые в Unity3d 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый день.
Есть 2 .cs скрипта. Первый скрипт выводит краткую информацию о задании:

```
public bool quest1;
public Text quest1Text;

public void Start()
{
    quest1 = false;
    quest1Text.text = "";
}

public void OnCLick_Button()
{
    quest1 = true;

     if (quest1)
    {
        Debug.Log("Задание взято");
        quest1Text.text = "Например - что бы выполнить задание, необходимо прочитать книгу.";
    }
}
```

Второй скрипт, по задумке, должен менять булевую переменную Quest1:

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    AcceptQuest.quest1 = false;
}
```

Если я в первом файле делаю переменные статичными, то в инспекторе объекта перестаёт отображаться булевая и текстовая переменная. Т.е при запуске я получаю предупреждение, что нет объектов, которые нужно показывать. Вопрос в том, как тогда мне передать значение из одного скрипта в другой?

Спасибо за помощь, Любитель.

Comment: А что значит в инспекторе нет? При запуске в редакторе статические переменные не пишутся, но они есть.

Comment: Но ведь способов масса.......например через `var go = GameObject.Find("someGameObjectOnScene").gameObject.GetComponent<YourComponent>()` и манипулировать через `go`...`go.quest1 = false/true;`..... А если статические переменные, то сразу `var questVar = Somescript.quest1;` ............ а в инспекторе не отображаются потому, что статические переменные относятся к классу а не к объекту....а компонент вы можете накидать на множество префабов... ...и как в этом случае юнити должен разруливать ситуацию и при этом чтоб вы не запутались, что эта переменная именно класса а не объекта?

Comment: Я не смог разобраться, почему при использовании модификатора `static` объявленные переменные пропадают из инспектора, но суть в том, что переменные работают даже в этом случае. Поэтому, я просто добавил статусы выполнения задания (обычная `int` переменная) и смог решить задачу с получением, выполнением и сдачей задания.

Comment: Я же вам писал почему.... статическая переменная не привязана к объекту, она относится только к классу поэтому она не может быть отображены в инспекторе....Ибо может возникнуть путаница, что вы будете менять её у каждого объекта в инспекторе, в надежде, что она будет для каждого объекта своя, а в итоге она будет меняться  у всех объектов.... Логично, что для того, чтоб избежать таких косяков она там и не отображается......... вам стоит почитать вообще о том, что такое статическая переменная, чтоб более полно понять, почему так происходит

Comment: Решил как отдельный вопрос сделать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513204/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0    ...... там есть решение через `SuctomEditor` .... то что вы ищите... Только это скорее костыль, нежели решение... удачи в разработках

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможность отображать статические обьекты в инспекторе не предоставляется с коробки. Хотя я гдето видел костыль как можно отображать, но там нужно править файлы скриптов самого юнити едитора. ( https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html ) И это считается плохим тоном.

> Вопрос в том, как тогда мне передать значение из одного скрипта в другой?

Существует 3 способа.

1. В нужном обьекте создаешь инстанс скрипта из цытаты 1. А потом в инспекторе перетягиваешь обьект с навешанным на нем скриптом в соответствующее поле
2. В Start найти нужный обьект по имени и достать с него нужный компонент `GameObject.Find("имя").GetComponent<имяСкриптаИзЦитаты1>()
3. Узнать что такое синглтон