# Почему статические переменные не видны в инспекторе редактора?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть скрипт:

```
public bool flag;
public Text description;

public void Start() {
    flag = false;
    description.text = "";
}
```

В этом скрипте имеются публичные переменные, они отображаются в инспекторе, можно там же изменять их значения, манипулировать во время программы.

Но если я в файле делаю эти переменные статическими, чтобы их можно было использовать в других скриптах, то в инспекторе объекта эти переменные перестают отображаться.

Почему так и что делать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для начала, вам стоит детально изучить и понять в чем отличие обычных переменных и статических. Думаю, после этого, станет что-то яснее..

Вкратце: **не** статические переменные класса принадлежат **конкретному экземпляру** (то есть **для каждого** экземпляра класса она своя)

Ключевое слово `static` при определении переменной и методов указывает, что данные члены будут доступны для **всего класса**, то есть на **ВСЕ** экземпляры класса у нас есть **только одна** переменная. Получить доступ к такой переменой можно только для самого класса без создания его экземпляра.

**Через конкретный  экземпляр класса доступа к такой переменной нет. Т. е. использовать такую статическую переменную можно только для самого класса без создания экземпляра.**

---

Когда `script` прикрепляется к какому-либо префабу/объекту, то, по сути, этот объект становится автоматически экземпляром данного класса (аналог `MyClass myObj = new MyClass()`) и все публичные переменные, не статические переменные становятся видны в инспекторе.

Далее...

Использовать статические переменные в экземплярах скриптов, как правило, признак плохого дизайна. И так как в `Unity` объекты подвергаются сериализации, то нужно сериализовать и статическую переменную, а как её потом восстанавливать? Какой объект должен будет инициализировать её в первый раз? Плюс еще если есть, например, 100 объектов-экземпляров класса в котором находится статическая переменная, то в процессе сериализации значение переменной может быть изменено (например, если используются несколько потоков), и получиться, что часть объектов сериализовалась с одним значением, остальная часть — с другим. Много проблем в общем.

Если хотите хранить какие-то глобальные параметры общие для объектов определённого типа, то лучше используйте `ScriptableObject`, практически для этого и создан.

Также, возможно, для некоторых случаев и глобальных настроек использовать [Singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/AManagerClass)

Пример использования: `gameManager`:

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Completed
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;       //Allows us to use Lists. 
    
    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public static GameManager instance = null;              //Static instance of GameManager which allows it to be accessed by any other script.
        private BoardManager boardScript;                       //Store a reference to our BoardManager which will set up the level.
        private int level = 3;                                  //Current level number, expressed in game as "Day 1".

        //Awake is always called before any Start functions
        void Awake()
        {
            //Check if instance already exists
            if (instance == null)
                
                //if not, set instance to this
                instance = this;
            
            //If instance already exists and it's not this:
            else if (instance != this)
                
                //Then destroy this. This enforces our singleton pattern, meaning there can only ever be one instance of a GameManager.
                Destroy(gameObject);    
            
            //Sets this to not be destroyed when reloading scene
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            
            //Get a component reference to the attached BoardManager script
            boardScript = GetComponent<BoardManager>();
            
            //Call the InitGame function to initialize the first level 
            InitGame();
        }
        
        //Initializes the game for each level.
        void InitGame()
        {
            //Call the SetupScene function of the BoardManager script, pass it current level number.
            boardScript.SetupScene(level);
            
        }
        
        
        
        //Update is called every frame.
        void Update()
        {
            
        }
}
```

**[Пример более подробно...](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/writing-game-manager)**

А также небольшой пример по созданию гейм менеджера можно посмотреть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491737/191482

Answer (score 4):

Если вам так хочется видеть статическую переменную, то сделать это можно через [CustomEditor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html). Так вы можете сделать ее вывод в ваш компонент в редакторе и при необходимости даже изменять ее. Только коллеги правы, использовать таким образом статические переменные это признак плохой архитектуры.

Comment: Вот и дырка в юнити - статика в инспекторе через кастомный......Хотя может иногда и нужно увидеть манипуляции таким образом

Comment: Это не дырка, скорей исключение, иногда действительно удобно увидеть статику, но как правило в этом нет нужды. При желании в компоненте без лишних движений можно смотреть приватные переменные в дебаговом режиме, так что редактор очень грамотно сделан. Вы можете сделать свой велосипед, но я этим доволен вполне)))