# Static поля в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, static, singleton

Можно как-то назначить static поле прямо в инспекторе Unity?
Допустим у меня есть список...

```cs
public static List<GameObject> objList = new List<GameObject>();
```

... его элементы мне надо назначить в инспекторе Unity.
Что в таком случае можно сделать?

Comment: Static напрямую не видно в инспекторе, так что ответ именно на ваш вопрос - нет.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513204/199253 . назначайте в коде, либо через синглтон

Comment: @СергейМишин  Спасибо!Замечательная статья!То что нужно!!

Comment: Можно написать скрипт прослойку, который будет на `Awake` переносить заполненное поля инспектора в соответствующие `static`.